# Check if elements are part of wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can't figure out how to check if I click on one of elements inside the wrapper then that element is really child of the wrapper!!!
I used event.target to detect where I'm clicking. I need to understand how to traverse through DOM!!!

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guntarwi/mxfja5h5/1/)

```html
<div class="task">
<span class="task-time">
  Tomorrow
</span>
  <div class="task-name">
    <span>
      Buy milk
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for my bad English I really don't know how to correctly ask this question I hope you will understand!!!

Comment: "`inside of the wrapper tag`" well that is not helpful

Comment: the event should propagate up to the wrapper.  so delegate the event to instances of the tag that live inside the wrapper.  or just set events through the parent like `document.querySelector('#wrapper > .tag')`

Comment: we all sometimes `need loop throe doom!!!`